# JS Find indices of duplicate values in array if there are more than two duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, duplicates

I'm creating coordinate plane Three in a row game so I have to find out if there are three numbers of the same value in the array BUT WITHOUT sorting array because the array represents the x-coordinates of the points added to the coordinate plane during the game...
For example, let's say that I've added 6 points to the coordinate plane with x-coordinates stored in next array:

```
var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];
```

I need the loop that will count only the occurrences of the value 2 because the number 2 occurs 3 times in array, so the output should be a new array (for example array named indices) with the exact indices of nmb 2 occurrences in arr...

```
indices = [0,1,3]
```

The loop should therefor "reset" when comes to the end of the arr if the number of occurrences of some value is less than 3...

I've tried the next code, but it doesn't work like I've described above because it counts the number of occurrences of the number 3 as well... so, it won't "reset" if value count is less than 2...

```
var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];
var index = [];
var count = 0;
var current;
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    current = arr[i];
    //-------------------------------
    for(var j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
        if(arr[j]===current){
            count++;
            index.push(j);
            //+++++++++++
            if(j===arr.length-1){
                if(count<2){
                    count = 0;
                    index = [];
                    i++;
                }
                else{
                    index.unshift(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //+++++++++++
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------
}
alert(index);
```

Thanks for any help or advice...

Aleksandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using some logic...

```js
var arr = [2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 3];

function showDupPos(arr, mindups) {
  mindups = mindups || 2;
  var result = [];
  var positions = {};
  // collect all positions
  arr.forEach(function(value, pos) {
    positions[value] = positions[value] || [];
    positions[value].push(pos);
  });
  //check how much of same value in string
  Object.keys(positions).forEach(function(value) {
    var posArray = positions[value];
    if (posArray.length > mindups) {
      result = result.concat(posArray);
    }
  });
  return result.sort();
}
console.log(showDupPos(arr));
```

Comment: zb' I've just run code snippet and it works perfectly! Unfortunately I've never posted here so I don't know how to like your answer or something like that...

Comment: I'm really stupid and I've accidentally clicked down arrow besides your answer so now there is -1 above besides my post and, as I've previously mentioned I've never posted here, now I don't know how to undo this action?? After that I've clicked up arrow several times but nothing happend... Sorry sorry...

Comment: Just click after some time

Answer (score 8):

I would do like this way

```js
  
var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];

var indices = [];

arr.filter(function(yourArray, index) {
 if(yourArray == 2){
   indices.push(index)
 }
});
console.log(indices)
```

if you print the indices it will contain this output 
[0,1,3]

if you want to check that there are more then two duplicates you you can do this way

```js
  

var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];
var counts = arr.filter(function(yourArr,index, self){
  return !self.indexOf(yourArr) 
});

var indices = [];

arr.filter(function(yourArr, index, self){
  if(yourArr == 2 && counts.length > 2){
   indices.push(index)
 }
})
console.log(indices)
```

Comment: I don't think OP needs to check for just 2, i think for `var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3,3];` it should be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

Comment: Thanks for your effort and suggestion, but as in previous comment I don't need loop just for one certain value/number but i need to loop through array and if a certain (not predefined) value occurs 3 or more than 3 times, the output array should contain the indices of occurences of that value in the original array...

Comment: That's just the idea how it works. You can wrap code into function and provide whatever value you want.

Comment: Thanks! But it would be great and much easier if there would be a predefined value whose occurrences should be counted... But that value depends on the nmb of occurrences in arr - the value of the number that appears 3 or more times in the one for which I need indices in the arr... So there isn't predefined value in the loop...

Comment: You could just do like this                        if (counts.length >2 &&yourArray ==counts[0]){ indices.push (index)}               counts array contain the same same value so you just could match your value at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

[this is my solution](http://codepen.io/ji_in_coding/pen/WxJZBX).

```
var arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];

var dictionary = {};
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if(dictionary[arr[i]]){
    dictionary[arr[i]]++;
  }else{
    dictionary[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}

for(var num in dictionary){
  if(dictionary[num] == 3){
    alert(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I've tried myself with the key=>value array and the output is the number of occurrences but I need the indices of those occurrences in the original array...

Answer (score 1):

here is a function that return an array of duplicate element's indexes

```js
let letters = ["b","a","f","g","h","v","s","e","a","t","h","d","z","r", "a", "f" ]
function duplicateIndexes(arr, el){

    duplicate = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] == el){
            duplicate.push(i)
        } 
    }
    return duplicate
}
let d = duplicateIndexes(letters, "a")
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like this:

```
Input:
array = ["same", "same", "duo", "same", "duo", "lonely", "same"];

Output:
indices = {
    "same": [0, 1, 3, 6],
    "duo": [2, 4],
    "lonely": [5]
}
```

Try this code

```
let array = ["same", "same", "duo", "same", "duo", "lonely", "same"];
let indices = {};

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!indices[array[i]]) {
        indices[array[i]] = [];
    }
    indices[array[i]].push(i);
}

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the desired result using filter or reduce.

Approach using filter -

```
    const arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];
    var keys = [];
    var filtered = arr.filter((e, i) => {
    if (e === 2) {
        keys.push(i);
    }
    });
    console.log(keys);
```

using reduce

```
    const arr = [2,2,3,2,7,3];

    const indexes = arr.reduce((r, n, i) => {
    n === 2 && r.push(i);
    
    return r;
    }, []);

    console.log(indexes);
```

One can wrap this logic inside a function to get the desired result without need of repeating the code at different places.

Answer (score 0):

this function covers all my duplicate finding needs

```js
function findAllDuplicatesInListOfObjects(list, prop) {
  const duplicates = [];
  const len = list.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (list[i][prop] === list[j][prop]) {
        const index = duplicates.findIndex(e => e[prop] === list[i][prop]);
        if (index != -1) {
          if (!duplicates[index].indexes.includes(j)) {
            duplicates[index].indexes.push(j);
          }
        } else {
          duplicates.push({
            indexes: [i, j],
            [prop]: list[i][prop],
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}

const users = [
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'aa' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'bb' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'cc' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'dd' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'ee' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'cc' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'bb' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'cc' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'aa' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'bb' },
  { name: 'user', pushtoken: 'cc' },
];

const duplicates = findAllDuplicatesInListOfObjects(users, 'pushtoken');

console.log(duplicates);
```

results

```bash
[
  { indexes: [ 0, 8 ], pushtoken: 'aa' },
  { indexes: [ 1, 6, 9 ], pushtoken: 'bb' },
  { indexes: [ 2, 5, 7, 10 ], pushtoken: 'cc' }
]
```