# Find indices of all duplicate records in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have an array as below:

```
Arr1 = [12,30,30,60,11,12,30]
```

I need to find index of elements which are repeated in array e.g.

```
ans: 0,1,2,5,6
```

I've tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533160/js-find-indices-of-duplicate-values-in-array-if-there-are-more-than-two-duplicat) code but it is considering just single element to check duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get all the duplicates using `filter()` and then using `reduce()` get he indexes of only those elements of array which are in `dups`

```js
const arr = [12,30,30,60,11,12,30];
const dups = arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) !== arr.lastIndexOf(x));
const res = arr.reduce((ac, a, i) => {
  if(dups.includes(a)){
    ac.push(i)
  }
  return  ac;
}, []);
console.log(res)
```

The time complexity of above algorithm is `O(n^2)`. If you want `O(n)` you can use below way

```js
const arr = [12,30,30,60,11,12,30];
const dups = arr.reduce((ac, a) => (ac[a] = (ac[a] || 0) + 1, ac), {})
const res = arr.reduce((ac, a, i) => {
  if(dups[a] !== 1){
    ac.push(i)
  }
  return  ac;
}, []);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach with an object as closure for seen items which holds an array of index and the first array, in which later comes the index and a necessary flattening of the values.

> This answer is based on the question how is it possible to insert a value into an already mapped value.
>
> This is only possible by using an object reference which is saved at the moment where a value appears and which is not seen before.
>
> Example of unfinished result
>
> ```
> [
>     [0],
>     [1],
>     2,
>     [],
>     [],
>     5,
>     6
> ]
> ```
>
> The final [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) removes the covering array and shows only the index, or nothing, if the array remains empty.
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]
> ```

```js
var array = [12, 30, 30, 60, 11, 12, 30],
    indices = array
        .map((o => (v, i) => {
            if (o[v]) {               // if is duplicate
                o[v][1][0] = o[v][0]; // take the first index as well
                return i;             // return index
            } 
            o[v] = [i, []];           // save index
            return o[v][1];           // return empty array
        })({}))
        .flat()                       // remove [] and move values out of array

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use simple `indexOf` and the loop to get the duplicate indexes.

```js
let arr = [12,30,30,60,11,12,30]
let duplicate = new Set();
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let index = arr.indexOf(arr[i], i + 1);
    if(index != -1) {
      duplicate.add(i);
      duplicate.add(index);
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(duplicate).sort().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#reduce` method

1. loop the array with `reduce`.At the time find the index of argument
2. And check the arguments exist more than one in the array using `Array#filter`
3. Finaly push the index value to new `accumulator` array.If the index value already exist in accumalator.Then pass the currentIndex `curInd` of the array to accumulator

```js
const arr = [12, 30, 30, 60, 11, 12, 30];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, b, curInd) => {
  let ind = arr.indexOf(b);
  if (arr.filter(k => k == b).length > 1) {
    if (acc.indexOf(ind) > -1) {
      acc.push(curInd)
    } else {
      acc.push(ind);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be easiest way to find indexes of duplicate elements

```
var dupIndex = [];
$.each(Arr1, function(index, value){
    if(Arr1.filter(a => a == value).length > 1){ dupIndex.push(index); }
});
```

This should work for you